# Mismatch between the equation of the equinoxes and the correction for a right ascension

Tags: coordinate, positional-astronomy

I am studying about apparent and mean positions of Sun using quite old books: *Astronomical algorithms* (1991) and *Explanatory supplement to the astronomical almanac* (1992).

The question is about the mismatch between the equation of the equinoxes and the correction for a right ascension. It seems like these two are the same concept. However, their equations do not seem to be matched.

According to the p.116 of the second book, the *equation of the equinoxes* refers to the nutation in right ascension. It is defined as follows:
$$ \Delta \psi \cos \epsilon $$
where $\Delta \psi$ is the *nutation in longitude* and $\epsilon$ is the *true obliquity of the ecliptic* (i.e., correction about the nutation is applied).

However, according to the p.120 of the same book, the first order correction $\Delta \alpha$ to the right ascension $\alpha$ is as follows:
$$\Delta \alpha = \left ( \cos \epsilon + \sin \epsilon \sin \alpha \sin \delta \right ) \Delta \psi - \cos \alpha \tan \delta \Delta \epsilon$$
where $\delta$ is the declination.

Because $\epsilon$ is about 23.4 degrees and others are arbitrary values, $\Delta \alpha$ cannot be approximated as $ \Delta \psi \cos \epsilon $.

It seems like there is some assumptions that I am missing or there is a problem in my understanding. I would like to ask help for this problem.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_nutation#Effect_on_position_of_astronomical_objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of the equinoxes only applies to the origin, so it is assumed $ \delta = 0 $. So $\tan \delta = 0, \sin \delta = 0 $, which means your second equation simplifies to $\Delta\psi \cos \epsilon $.